# Does std::make_shared perform value initialization (GCC and clang disagree)?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer

What I take to mean can be explained by the following example:

`auto p = std::make_shared<int>();`

Is the `int` variable default initialized (thus have garbage value) or value initialized (thus have a value of zero)? I've tested on GCC 5.2 and clang 3.6 with the former doing value initialization and the latter doing default initialization. I'm wondering what does the standard say about this? In my opinion, modern C++ should definitely perform value initialization in this case.

Comment: _"I've tested on GCC 5.2 and clang 3.6 with the former doing value initialization and the latter doing default initialization."_ I'm surprised by your result for clang, how did you test it?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I tested it on the online compiler embedded in cppref.

Comment: But how? What code did you write to verify the behaviour?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Select `clang 3.6 (C++14)` and run `std::cout << *std::make_shared<int>();` My run outputs the result `132080`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The run on Coliru online compiler itself gives the right result though. Don't know why.

Comment: Checking the result of `*std::make_shared<int>();` is enough to verify that it is default initialized, if it evaluates to something non-zero. But if it's zero, you can't know, whether it is actually value initialized or default initialized and just zero by coincidence. You'd have to check the assembler code to know for sure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes.**

N3797 20.8.2.2.6

> Allocates memory suitable for an object of type T and constructs an
>   object in that memory via the placement new expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

So, here will be

```
::new (pv) int();
```

And so on by N3797 8.5.1

> The initialization that occurs in the forms
>
> ```
> T x(a);
> T x{a};
> ```
>
> as well as in new expressions (5.3.4) is called direct-initialization.
>
> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is
>   the type of the object or reference being initialized and the source
>   type is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is
>   not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is
>   not defined.
>
> — If the initializer is `()`, the object is value-initialized.
>
> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

And both new clang and GCC agree with the standard: [Live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Q7vctUOjyZPCV8S4)

Answer (score 6):

The standard seems to support your opinion.

From 20.8.2.2.6:

> constructs an object in that memory via the placement new-expression ::new (pv) T(std::forward(args)...)

Since new int() is value initialized, as contrasted with new int, I would expect zero.