# why c++ use memset(addr,0,sizeof(T)) to construct a object? Standard or compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, perfect-forwarding

This question is related to another post of mine: [why allocate_shared and make_shared so slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072486/why-allocate-shared-and-make-shared-so-slow)

In here I can describe the question more clearly.

Think about the following code:

```
struct A {
    char data_[0x10000];
};

class C {
public:
    C() : a_() { }
    A a_;
};

int main() {
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

I found for the code `C() : a_()`, the compiler uses `memset(addr,0,0x10000)` as the constructor of the A. And if the type A has a empty constructor, the asm code is right.

To describe the issue more clearly, I wrote some test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
    //A() {}
    char data_[0x10000];
    void dummy() { // avoid optimize erase by compiler
        data_[rand() % sizeof(data_)] = 1;
    }
    int dummy2() { // avoid optimize erase by compiler
        return data_[0];
    }
};

class B {
public:
    template<class ... T> B(T&...t) 
        : a_(std::forward<T>(t)...) {
    }
    A a_;
};

class C {
public:
    C() : a_() {
    }
    A a_;
};

template<class ... T>
int test(T&...t) {
    A a(t...);
    a.dummy();
    return a.dummy2();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.dummy();
    auto r1 = a.dummy2();

    auto r2 = test();

    B b;
    b.a_.dummy();
    auto r3 = b.a_.dummy2();

    C c;
    c.a_.dummy();
    auto r4 = c.a_.dummy2();
    return r1 + r2 + r3 + r4;
}
```

I compiled the code with vs2017, in windows 10, x86 release build.
Then I checked the asm code:

```
template<class ... T>
int test(T&...t) {
00E510B8  call        _chkstk (0E51CE0h)  
00E510BD  mov         eax,dword ptr [__security_cookie (0E53004h)]  
00E510C2  xor         eax,ebp  
00E510C4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax  
    A a(t...);
00E510C7  push        10000h  
00E510CC  lea         eax,[a]  
00E510D2  push        0  
00E510D4  push        eax  
00E510D5  call        _memset (0E51C3Ah)  
00E510DA  add         esp,0Ch  
    a.dummy();
00E510DD  call        dword ptr [__imp__rand (0E520B4h)]  
}
00E510E3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4]
```

It is very clear that the function `test()` calls `memset(p, 0, 0x10000)`.

And if I add an empty constructor in A (line `A(){}`), the compiler removes the memset.

So why does the code call memset when type A does not have constructor but does not call memset when A has a constructor?

Is it part of the c++ standard, or just a compiler bug?

Obviously the memset(p, 0, sizeof(T)) is useless and harmful which slows down the program. How do I workaround it?

Comment: This looks like the difference between default-initialization and zero-initialization.  I'm hazy on the details, though, so see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484483/default-initialization-versus-zero-initialization

Comment: There is no `test2()` function...

Comment: @K.Kirsz test, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
A a(t...);
```

Will be parsed as initializing `a` with `t...`.<sup>†</sup> When `t...` is empty, as when you call it, this will be understood as *value-initializing* `a`.

For `A` without a user-provided default constructor, *value-initialize* is to zero all its members, hence the `memset`.

When you provide a constructor for `A`, *value-initialize* is to call the default constructor, which you defined to be do nothing, therefore no `memset` will be called.

This is not a bug in the compiler, this is required behaviour. To remove the redundant `memset`, you could just write `A a;`. In this case `a` is *default-initialized* and no automatic zeroing occurs, with or without the user-provided constructor.

<sub>† This is important since `A a()` will be parsed as a function called `a` with return type `A`</sub>

Comment: Take a look at the class B, it's a standard perfect-forwarding. If the class A does not have a constructor, the B also call memset. How to workaround it? And, please move to the url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072486/why-allocate-shared-and-make-shared-so-slow , I found std::allocate_shared also do this useless memset and I do not know how to workaround it.

Comment: @alpha What do you mean move to the url. If the questions are duplicate, you are doing things wrong. If they are not, __don't ask multiple questions in one post__

Comment: @alpha `B` calls `a_()` in its constructor, this is covered __directly__ in the answer why `memset` is needed here.

Comment: I first meet the performance issue described by that url, and then I diged for some days, finally I found out it's because of the memset. It's not duplicate question. Even after I understand the value-initializing, I still do not know how to solve that issue.

Comment: If I change the define of A as struct A { A()=default;
    char data_[0x10000];
}; I found the compiler still call memset. Why? The compiler should generate a dummy constructor for A?

Comment: @alpha In that case, if `A` is value-initialized (as in `A a(t...);` above), then `A` is just zero-initialized, its constructor isn't called since it is also trivial. This part of C++ is just tedious to work through, I'd suggest just provide the exact constructor that you want to call to sidestep all this.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) explain it?

We can see that:

> Zero initialization is performed [...] as part of value-initialization
>   sequence for [...] members of **value-initialized** class types that have
>   no constructors, including value initialization of elements of
>   aggregates for which no initializers are provided.

...

> **Value initialization** is performed [...]  when a non-static data member
>   or a base class is initialized using a member initializer with an
>   empty pair of parentheses or braces (since C++11);

So putting `a_()` in the member initializer list falls into the latter case, that as a result invokes zero initialization of the array.

To answer your question: to me this seems to be a standard behavior not a compiler bug.